# SQLserver Store Column as variable and loop through it

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, loops

I am still pretty new to SQL server and I am not sure how to do this.  I am first creating a table with just the IDs I need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
ID_NUMBER
INTO
#IDlist
FROM
V_Rpt_IDs WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
ID_NUMBER in (
'1000764169'
,'1005870537'
,'1008053856'
,'1008054376'
,'1008410224'
,'1008411317'
,'1008465318'
,'1008466074'
,'1008492967'
,'1010546872'
,'1010554301')

Select * from #IDlist
```

And this works fine.  But now I would like to declare a variable to represent this column, or each item in this column, so that I can then do a loop where it loops through each ID Number and returns information about each one and then presents all of that as a table.  Here is my shot at that:

```
Declare @IDNumber as VARCHAR(10)
Set @IDNumber = #IDlist.ID_NUMBER

DECLARE @cnt INT = 0

WHILE @cnt < (Select Count(*) From #IDlist)
BEGIN
SELECT TOP 1
NAME
,MAILING_ADDRESS_1
,MAILING_ADDRESS_CITY
,MAILING_STATE
,MAILING_ZIP
from
V_Rpt_Info
WHERE
ID_NUMBER = @IDNumber

SET @cnt = @cnt + 1

END

DROP TABLE #IDlist
```

But when I Set the `@IDNumber` variable to `#IDlist.ID_NUMBER`, it says `The multi-part identifier "#IDlist.ID_NUMBER" could not be bound.`

How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way you set the variable is not correct, SQL doesn't know which ID_NUMBER row it should assign to the @IDNumber variable. 
You should do this with a SELECT, for example

```
SET @IDNumber = SELECT TOP 1 ID_NUMBER FROM #IDlist
```

But, why would you like to loop through this temporary table this way ? Isn't it possible to join the necessary data with this table instead of doing it one by one ?

Comment: oh, joining is probably a better way to do it.  I just didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

Rather then loop through, you're going to want to join your ID table to your V_Rpt_Info view.

```
SELECT
    NAME
  , MAILING_ADDRESS_1
  , MAILING_ADDRESS_CITY
  , MAILING_STATE
  , MAILING_ZIP
FROM V_Rpt_Info V
INNER JOIN #IDlist ID
ON V.ID_NUMBER = ID.ID_NUMBER
```